# Return to the client from within a service call, but continue executing the workflow?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I have a WF 4 service. I have the following sequence:

1. Receive activity
2. Some Other activities
3. SendReply
4. Other Activities

I have an asp.net calling this service. 
Why does this client has to wait for all steps to complete?
I want that when step 3 is completed, the reply is sent to the client and the client can continue on its own.

any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The response is ready to send but due to the async nature of WF4 it isn't actually send directly. You can either persist the workflow, using the PersistBeforeSend, or add a small sub second delay using a Delay activity.

Comment: Worked perfectly with the delay!! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

When the Workflow hits the SendReply block it should send the reply at that point and allow the client to continue on. You could test that by putting a delay in of a couple of minutes at Step 4.

Is it possible that the steps after the SendReply are completing so quickly that it just looks like the Workflow is running those steps before sending the reply?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is a long running process and screen just stops waiting. Somehow, setting presist before send at the reply, allows the client to continue.

Comment: That seems strange - in most cases it is probably a good idea to persist before sending the reply anyway - otherwise if there are exceptions after the reply the workflow will just terminate and not retry from the persistence point (which of course could be the behaviour you are after in some cases).

Comment: Wiredness  - FYI, please refer to Maurice replies. There seems to be a known issue due to async nature of WF. Thanks for your help as well.